# How to set default metric on IPv6 route received by RA message

Tags: linux, network-interface, routing, ipv6, priority

I have two ipv6 interfaces(eth1 and eth2), that receives an IP via DHCP(dhclient is used), but the routes are received via RA messages from switch, to which these interfaces are connected. Since RA messages does not provide a metric for routes(and it is supposed not to set metric from switch side), both of them are assigned for a default metric(1024) in kernel. In a result in 'ip -6 route show' the routes looks like:

```
default via fe80::fe33:4201:546:66e0 dev eth2 proto ra metric 1024 expires 56sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
default via fe80::fe33:4201:546:66e0 dev eth1 proto ra metric 1024 expires 56sec hoplimit 64 pref medium
```

So, I need to make eth1 to have higher priority than eht2 by setting a default metric for them and the question is how can I do it inside of the device?

I have tried several things but all of them can not be used in my case due to limitations:

1. netlink solution can only remove and add new route, but it is needed to be added by kernel via RA
2. Since I use old kernel(4.9.248-1.21pre), there is no way I can use net.ipv6.conf.eth0.net.ipv6.conf.eth0.ra_defrtr_metric to configure default metric.
3. Another DHCP client(e.g. DHCPCD) can not be used because I need to receive routes via RA. So all the other ways that considers to disable RA are excluded
4. I cant set metric in /etc/network/interfaces because the interfaces are manual and it is ignored

   `auto ethx`

   `iface ethx inet manual`

Comment: A tool like NetworkManager disables kernel's handling: sets net.ipv6.ethX.accept_ra = 0 and implements this in userspace. It creates the route with `proto ra` following its own metric scheme, allowing priorities etc. What prevents you from using such a tool or re-implementing this yourself? You didn't specific the environment. I guess from the old kernel it's an embedded device? You should state what is available or not. What Linux distribution? Even a shell loop with iproute2 commands and jq can work around your precise case. Is jq or else some other command like awk available? etc.